# Target class [App\\Http\\controllers\\AdminAuthController] does not exist after uploading in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, version, cpanel

I created a laravel rest api project in my local pc with php version 8.0.3. Everything works fine in the localhost. But when I upload the files to cpanel. Below error occurs.
My cpanel php version is 7.4.3.
I cleared the cache before uploading.

Here's the error I get:

```
{
"message": "Target class [App\\Http\\controllers\\AdminAuthController] does not exist.",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException",
"file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
"line": 875,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
        "line": 754,
        "function": "build",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",
        "line": 841,
        "function": "resolve",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
        "line": 692,
        "function": "resolve",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",
        "line": 826,
        "function": "make",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
        "line": 275,
        "function": "make",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
        "line": 1049,
        "function": "getController",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
        "line": 1010,
        "function": "controllerMiddleware",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 708,
        "function": "gatherMiddleware",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 688,
        "function": "gatherRouteMiddleware",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 672,
        "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 636,
        "function": "runRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 625,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 166,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 128,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
        "line": 31,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 21,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
        "line": 40,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
        "line": 86,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
        "line": 52,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 167,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 103,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 141,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 110,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/bmsswsxf/amrtvapi.bmssystems.org/public/index.php",
        "line": 52,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    }
]
```

}

Here's my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: your namespace must be the issue. try "App\Http\Controllers" instead of "App\Http\controllers" in imports. linux is case sensitive

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I was working on Mac which is not case sensitive.

Comment: Glad to be a help